# Civicrm on Wordpress installer table doesnt exist

Tags: wordpress, database, installation, mysql, issues

Using Ampp version 4.3 with Apache v2.4.54, MySQL v8.0.31, php version 7.4.32, Windows

Every time I run the CiviCrm installer I get an error "Table 'civicrm.civicrm_worldregion' doesn't exist in ... " I've tried to add the innodb settings in mysql.conf but mysql doesn't know these entries.
The table is indeed not present in my DB (using the same DB as wordpress).

I don't know how to continue and I would like to get some help. Thanks

Whole error message is `Fatal error: Uncaught Civi\Setup\Exception\SqlException: Cannot execute /******************************************************* * * civicrm_county * *******************************************************/ INSERT INTO civicrm_worldregion (id, name) VALUES("1", "Europe and Central Asia"): Table 'civicrm.civicrm_worldregion' doesn't exist in C:\Program Files\Ampps_4_2\www\civicrm.test\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\setup\src\Setup\DbUtil.php:206 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files\Ampps_4_2\www\civicrm.test\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\setup\plugins\installDatabase\InstallSchema.civi-setup.php(85): Civi\Setup\DbUtil::sourceSQL() #1 C:\Program Files\Ampps_4_2\www\civicrm.test\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php(264): InstallSchemaPlugin->installDatabase() #2 C:\Program Files\Ampps_4_2\www\civicrm.test\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php(239): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() #3 C:\Pro in C:\Program Files\Ampps_4_2\www\civicrm.test\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\setup\src\Setup\DbUtil.php on line 206`

Comment: Welcome to SE!  Have a look at your log file - are there errors in there before that one?

Comment: There are a bunch of warnings but only one fatal error. I've deleted my civicrm upload folder and run the installer again. A similar error is thrown. Now it's about the civicrm_acl table. 
Cannot execute LOCK TABLES `civicrm_acl` WRITE: Table 'civicrm.civicrm_acl' doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

PHP8 is not recommended, see the System Requirements [Docs here](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements/).

PLease try again with PHP7.4.

Comment: I'm running php version 7.4.
MySQL is version 8

Comment: Sorry, i have misread your Infos

Comment: I think those docs are a bit out of date now, CiviCRM itself runs fine with PHP 8.0 however some extensions might not be fully compatible.

Comment: I'll try it with php 8. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: So I've installed XAMPP because it comes with php8 out of the box and now I'm able to install and run Civicrm. Whether the issue is actually caused by an incompatible php version remains unclear.
Just a note for other people trying to run Civicrm wirh XAMPP or AMPPS. If you get an error about "Unable to load dynamic library "..../php_intl.dll" - The specified module could not be found." Open your xampp/php/php.ini and uncomment 'extension=intl'

Thanks all for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

I would try to manually create this missing table. there are only two columns: id (primary key with auto-increment) and name.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid that there is a more fundamental problem here and new queries will only fail if the problem isn't fixed properly.